# Terraform: How to generate key/value pairs

Tags: terraform

I need to generate map of key/value pairs from a list of IP addresses.

Example input:

```
ips = [ "1.2.3.4", "2.3.4.5"]
```

Desired output:

```
pairs = [ {ip_address="1.2.3.4"}, {ip_address="2.3.4.5"} ]
```

My TF input data is in `openstack_networking_port_v2.vip.*.all_fixed_ips.0` (arbitrary number of ip addresses) and what I need to generate is `allowed_address_pairs` parameter for `openstack_networking_port_v2`, like:

```
resource "openstack_networking_port_v2" "port" {
  name = "port"
  admin_state_up = "true"
  network_id = "${openstack_networking_network_v2.net-backend.id}"
  allowed_address_pairs = [ 
   { ip_address = "1.2.3.4" },
   { ip_address = "2.3.4.5" } 
  ]
}
```

But of course declaring `allowed_address_pairs` dynamically, from a resource like:

```
resource "openstack_networking_port_v2" "vip" {
  name = "vip-${count.index}"
  network_id = "${openstack_networking_network_v2.net-backend.id}"
  admin_state_up = "true"
  count = "10"
}
```

Any clue?

Comment: When you say "dynamically" - Where is it coming from? Do you want to pass this into the `terraform apply`? It it coming from another resource?

Comment: exactly - see my edit.